# perfect display on desktop but displays few elements on mobile

Tags: html, css

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
#heading {
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#heading-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 40vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background: #eee;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

main {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 30px 0px 40px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), -30px 0px 40px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
  display: block;
}

#heading-inner-text {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0;
  color: #888;
  margin-block-start: 0.83em;
  margin-block-end: 0.83em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
}

#image-heading h2 {
  border-left: dotted 1px #fff;
  border-right: dotted 1px #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2rem 0 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  transition: background 500ms ease;
}

#landing-image {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1522206024047-9c925421675b?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MXwxfDB8MXxhbGx8fHx8fHx8fA&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=1080&utm_source=unsplash_source&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=api-credit);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  flex: 0 1 60vw;
  margin: 0;
}

#images {
  display: block;
}

#image-heading {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  display: block;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
}

.caption {
  padding: 0.8rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

footer h3 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-block-start: 1em;
  margin-block-end: 1em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  margin: auto;
  color: #333;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  #heading {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #heading-text {
    height: 50vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  }
  #landing-image {
    background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/De8wMYoSSBc);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50vh;
    flex: 0 1 60vw;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
  }
  p {
    justify-content: center;
  }
  body {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    background: #eee;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>collins Photography</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div id="heading">
      <div id="heading-text">
        <div id="heading-inner-text">
          <h1>Jane's Photography</h1>
          <h2>Weddings And Kids</h2>
          <a href="#images" class="btn" id="view-work"> view work </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="landing-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="images">
      <div id="image-heading">
        <h2>Our Work
          <h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/happy-wedding-photography-of-bride-and-groom-at-wedding-ceremony-picture-id1190043570?k=20&m=1190043570&s=612x612&w=0&h=4ucKegbD9AHd99kH5uEqrtm5zovyZ6IsYa33hR2pV-k=" alt="">

    <div class="caption">
      <h3> Royalty
        <h3>
          <p>Couples who get married between the ages of 28 and 32 are far more likely to stay together for the long haul
            <p>

    </div>

    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/heres-to-the-beginning-of-our-happily-ever-after-picture-id1303804580?b=1&k=20&m=1303804580&s=170667a&w=0&h=wSgn20MtKU-aCSTLt7NQ_an_SAlQUGgsqFiBg8EonRM=">

    <div class="caption">
      <h3> Dignity
        <h3>
          <p>Ending the ceremony with a kiss because, according to ancient Rome, the kiss is a legal bond that seals the contract
            <p>

    </div>

    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/african-couple-picture-id1177074168?k=20&m=1177074168&s=612x612&w=0&h=htqlkLHZmdgMi6uDW9Yr6z5AseFGVMr3MUHu9Spg0lE=">

    <div class="caption">
      <h3> Satisfaction
        <h3>
          <p>True News: Marriage does more to promote life satisfaction than money or sex
            <p>

    </div>

    <img src="https://static.independent.co.uk/2021/05/22/13/newFile-1.jpg?width=640&auto=webp&quality=75" </main>

    <footer>
      <h3> Contact Us </h3>
      <p> Email or call us to setup a consult
        <p>
          <p> Email:
            <strong>janesphotos@gmail.com </srtong>
      </p>

      <p> Phone:
        <strong> (+1) 813 901 7777 </strong>
          </p>
    </footer>

</body>
<html>
```

please i'm new here and i need your help. this website is perfect on desktop view and when screen is reduced on desktop, but doesn’t show the full site on mobile. i have included all the media qweries, but only the first header elements display on mobile iphone 6. i've also included the meta tag but all to no avail. can you tell me whats wrong with my code? your solution is much appreciated. [here is a link to my codepen](https://codepen.io/frugalcodes/pen/RwZzvWZ)

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't show the full site"?